# Why does printf not work in Emacs octave-mode?

Tags: octave

I've recently started using Emacs **octave-mode** and discovered that when using `printf` Emacs seems to block and I have to kill the execution of an Octave script with `C-g`.

I can reproduce that problem by having a file `testprintf.m` with just that single following line:

> printf("Test");

or, alternatively, more authentical:

> printf("Test: %d", 10);

Then, I execute this file with `C-c C-i a` (or, if you like, just that line with `C-c C-i l`) and I am seeing the mouse pointer turning into the waiting symbol signalling me that this Emacs command seems to hang. `C-g` terminates the command and allows further editing of the buffer. The  Inferior Octave buffer does not show any output during and after this action.

Converting `printf` into a `disp` statement works but I'd like to make use of the convenient C-style formatting, Octave offers. Also, the same `printf` command **works when directly copied into the Inferior Octave buffer** with the expected out. I am using *GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.11)* and *Octave 4.4.1*. I have also tried it without my `~/.emacs` with the same result, the mouse pointer turning into the waiting symbol.

Comment: You don't say what actions you take to make Emacs hang. You just show some text. The question seems unclear, so far.

Comment: Thanks, alright, I added some details in the hope this make my issue clearer.

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce this, but I think it's a buffering issue: try

```
printf("Test\n");
```

instead. Without the newline, `accept-process-output` seems to wait indefinitely.

Re: the comment from the OP - it should be fine to have multiple printf's without newlines, as long as there is a printf *with* a newline that is at the end of the code  and is evaluated as part of that code - you just won't be able to evaluate things line by line. [LATER CORRECTION] But now that I have tried it, I see that it does not work: *every* printf has to have a newline, else `accept-process-output` waits indefinitely.

Comment: Thanks @NickD, indeed, adding a newline helps, e.g. `printf("Test: %d\n", 10);`. Sadly, newline's are what I frequently want to avoid to compose print output from different parts of the code in one line. Certainly, one can store output in variables, compose all into one call to `printf` with trailing `\n`. Still, a somewhat odd behaviour.